# Where does Sharepoint 2010 codes goes and SP Audit Reports

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I know it's a weird question, and possibly to easy for almost all of you, sorry for that, but I am extremely new on Sharepoint (actually, extreeeemely new!). So here's my doubt..

I need to do generate automatically audit reports of some libraries in SP2010 but not manual with `Site Collection Administration > Audit Log Reports`.

I need to report every time an user OPENS a document on the library, and register that on a document each time that happens maybe.. so i need to do the audit report automatically, but i don't know how.

I heard that with this code i can do it (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spauditquery.aspx), but first i don't even know where does the code goes in sharepoint, i see this kind of code everywhere but i don't know where it goes, and second.. i don't even know how to start with my automatic audit reports..

If someone could help me, it'd be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your requirements for example if you want a live view of the audit data then you could add the code to a `Web Part` and place this on a page in the site so when a user visits the page they see the stats that are generated at that particular instant.

This could have performance implications for the page load time depending on the size of the audit data so you may want to create a custom `Timer Job` to run the code you could then set the schedule for this to run nightly and save the audit report out to a document library.

If you need guidance on how to create `Web Parts`

[Web Parts in SharePoint Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms476318%28v=office.14%29.aspx) - This also has a [Walkthrough for Creating a Basic Web Part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms415817%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

or `Timer Jobs`

[Andrew Connell - Creating Custom SharePoint Timer Jobs](http://www.andrewconnell.com/Creating-Custom-SharePoint-Timer-Jobs) and [DotNet Finder - Creating Custom Timer Job in SharePoint 2010](http://dotnetfinder.wordpress.com/2010/07/24/creatingcustomsharepointtimerjob2010/)